# Setting all keys to have the same value by using an iterator

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

I created a hashmap to represent a graph. The keys in my hash map are the vertices and the values are the edges. From my hashmap I take all of its vertices and store them in a dictionary called vertexDictionary. I would now like to set all the values of the vertex dictionary to False but I am having trouble with this. I tried to use an iterator but I am getting an error in my code with the starred line. My code is below:

```
public void clearMarks(){
// Sets marks for all vertices to false.
  Set set = graph.entrySet();
  Iterator i = set.iterator();

  while(i.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry g = (Map.Entry)i.next();
    *this.graph.put(g.getKey(), false);*
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Is `graph` declared using generics (e.g. `Map<String, Boolean> graph;`)? If so that line won't compile because you are using raw types.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 0):

The getKey() method returns Object. The problem is that you don't cast it. Let's say your keys are integer, then you should change your code to this:

```
this.graph.put((int) g.getKey(), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `vertexDictionay` which contains all the vertices that you are interested in, and for each of those you want to set them to `False`.

So I assume that you have some data structure like `Map<Integer, Boolean> vertexDictionay;`

You should be able to

```
    for (Map.Entry vertex : vertexDictionay.entrySet()) {
        vertex.setValue(false);
    }
```

The foreach loop uses an iterator under the hood as discussed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html). This fixes your argument mismatch error and is more readable IMHO